# Filtering entries from a Core Data entity that appear in an NSPopUpButton list

Tags: cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, nspopupbuttoncell

I'm familiar with how to feed data from one Core Data entity into an `NSPopUpButton` item so that it can be selected for another.  Bindings like so:

For the values themselves:

```
-> ValueSelection.Content
    Bind To: Value Source Entity
    Controller Key: arrangedObjects
    Model Key: N/A
```

For the values displayed in the `NSPopUpButton`:

```
-> ValueSelection.ContentValues
    Bind to: Same entity as ValueSelection.Content
    Controller Key: arrangedObjects
    Model Key: the name of the attribute you wish to have displayed
```

To link it to the destination value:

```
-> ValueSelection.SelectedObject
    Bind to: Destination entity
    Controller Key: selection
    Model Key: Name of the attribute/relationship in the destination entity.
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out if there is a way to set up a filter (I'm guessing in `ContentValues`) where you can only have it grab entries from that entity that have a certain attribute flag checked (e.g. say I'm pulling from my `users` entity and I just wanted to list male or female users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSArrayController has a "[filter predicate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/setFilterPredicate:)", which can be set in Interface Builder or in code (via the method in the docs to which I linked). See the [Predicates Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) to figure out what predicate you'll need to supply for your desired filter.